# How to navigate from widget extension to UIKit viewController?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, widget

I am currently trying to make a widget with SwiftUI.
Let's say my code is like this:

```
struct WidgetView: View {
    var data : DataProvider.Entry
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Image("Clicker")
                .padding(.all, 15)
        }.widgetURL(URL(string: "ClickerViewController"))
        .padding(.all, 30)
        .background(Color.green)
    }
}
```

At the moment, tapping the widget opens the home screen of the app. Want to navigate to a specific screen.
supportedFamilies: .**systemSmall** - so need to use .**widgetURL** and not .Link

So where the URL is Clicker, how to navigate to viewController that is called `ClickerViewController`?
How to handle these links? Any examples or explaining would help me and a lot of others in the near future I guess ;)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is possible approach

```
var body: some Scene {
    @StateObject private var appState = AppState()

    WindowGroup {
        ContentView()
            .environmentObject(appState)
            .onOpenURL(perform: { url in
                appState.handle(url)       // redirect to app state
            })
    }
}
```

and `AppState` can have, for example

```
class AppState: ObservableObject {
    @Published var appScreen: _SomeEnumType_

    func handle(url: URL) {
        // ... update `appScreen` here correnspondingly
    }
}
```

so inside `ContentView` depending on app state you can switch shown views.

Answer (score 2):

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) {

}
```

I got this method performed in `SceneDelegate` when I clicked the widget. You can handle your url and redirect to the ViewController