# How to use Link in WidgetKit to define arbitrary regions, not just text links?

Tags: swiftui, widgetkit

In the session "Widgets Code Along Part 2" in WWDC 2020, [the presenter says](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020-10035/?time=174):

> Widgets do not have animation or custom interactions, but we can deep link from our widget into our app. SystemSmall widgets are one large tap area, while systemMedium and systemLarge can use the new SwiftUI link API to create tappable zones within the widget.

This suggests that I should be able to designate regions of my widget as tappable that lead to a given URL in my app. But the [`Link`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/link) API just takes a string title and a destination URL - it doesn't appear to be able to embed other arbitrary views like images.

How do I use the `Link` API to designate regions of my widget as tappable, instead of just text links?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63810770/how-to-navigate-from-widget-extension-to-uikit-viewcontroller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type definition of `Link` is actually `struct Link<Label> where Label : View` so the only constraint to `Label` is that it conforms to the `View` protocol (despite the name indicating otherwise). My preferred initializer is `init(destination:, label:)` so you can embed every view in the view builder like this:

```
Link(destination: URL(string: "some://dest")!) {
  HStack {
    Text("I'm part of the tappable area")
    Text("Me too")
  }
}
```

You can actually see this in action in the Emoji Rangers project from Apple (check `AllCharactersView.swift`.