# Is it possible to navigate to a certain route when I press on the Widget versus when I press on the app Icon?

Tags: swiftui, widgetkit

I want my app to always access Screen A when pressing on the widget and screen B when pressing on our app icon. I was able to make the app always access Screen A when pressing on the widget but is it possible to always access screen B when pressing on the app? Because right now, when I open the app through widget, close the app then open it again through our app, it opens screen A instead of screen B.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/63812261/12299030?

Comment: @Asperi I get that you can detect if the user pressed on the widget but how do I detect if the user pressed on the app?

Comment: When user pressed the app icon there is no URL